# How to check the Domain Authority of outbound links?

Tags: seo

I am not talking about backlink analysis.

What I want to do is check the domain authority of all of my outbound links. I am specifically interested if some of the sites I have linked to in the past have become "bad neighborhoods".

I am asking this because I noticed that some of the sites I am currently linking to have been "hijacked" for SEO purposes. What I mean is, someone has bought the site and / or domain and this has become a site where I don't want to lead my own visitors anymore.

However, as I have thousands of outbound links, checking them manually is too much.

Is there a way for me to grab all my outbound links and run them through some API to check for their current stats, eg. Domain Authority?

Comment: I'm not sure checking the domain authority is a great signal for link checking.   I've had success in running a link checker that report which URLs redirect or give errors.   It would be even better if a link checker remembered what the page is supposed to be about and told you when it changes significantly.

Comment: Yeah, I know some affiliate link management systems do this. However, I am not aware of solutions for all outgoing links.

Answer (score 2):

I see were you're going with this. I like it. Moz can get you the DA.

You'll have to get a list of links from the site and filter out what you don't want. Uses lynx text browser, awk, grep.

```
lynx -dump nike.com | awk '/http/{print $2}' | grep -v '^https://www.nike.com'
```

Once you have the list of links to 3rd party sites, you can loop through the list, calling Moz api (paid), and filtering the responses as needed. Alternatively, if you're not a CLI guru, you can use Moz with Google Sheets, which is pretty solid, and probably a better way to keep an eye on this in an ongoing fashion.

https://moz.com/help/links-api/making-calls/url-metrics
https://moz.com/blog/moz-api-google-sheets
https://moz.com/products/api/pricing